# Animation not showing in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I've this example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(0.5 * x + phase))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

It is working in `pyCharm` but not in `Spyder`. I've tried `%matplotlib qt5` and changing the iPython Graphics output tool but noone worked: it just appear when my animation is done. What else can I do?

Comment: Tried and works fine in regular IPython shell. What is output of `matplotlib.get_backend()`? If it's not `'TkAgg'`, try changing it into it with `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`.

Comment: @np8 it sais `ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'qt5' is currently running` when i try to use `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`

Comment: Maybe you can only change it in Spyder settings: Tools > preferences > Graphics > Backend > TkAgg. ? And after change, you need to restart the IPython kernel.

Comment: @np8 there is not TkAgg option there :/

Comment: Did you try through all the other possible choices there?

Comment: @np8 I've even updated Spyder